# How to count number of days of each month in particular date range in php dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I would like to say thanks first to you for spending time on my problem.

For example user selected 10 Dec 2016 to 20 April daterange. then how can i get the no. of days of Dec, Jan, Feb, March and April in that range. ie. Dec=22 Days, Jan=31 Days, Feb=28 Days, March=31 Days and April=20 Days.

I am making attendance report for Employees. In attendance report user will select the date range to get the attendance report.

Attendance report view is looking like as shown below

[image]

As shown in above image month number is shown in first row of table i.e.

[image]

But I want to show No. of month in merged column like this. 
[image]

Please guide me to make this thing done. Thanks You very much again.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code so we can help you.

Comment: @TomUdding I want to colspan dynamically  month headers according to daterange.

Comment: Hi, you need to try some code and then if you are facing any issues with your code we can figure it out.

Comment: You can try cal_days_in_month to get number of days in a given month and year
http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php

Comment: That i know dear. For example user selected 10 Dec 2016 to 20 April daterange. then how can i get the no. of days of Dec, Jan, Feb, March and April in that range. ie. Dec=22 Days, Jan=31 Days, Feb=28 Days, March=31 Days and April=20 Days.

Comment: Now that makes your question more clear, you can edit your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
<?php
    $begin = new DateTime( '2016-12-10' );
    $end = new DateTime( '2017-04-20' );

    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
    $period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $period as $dt ){
        if($i==0){
            $month[$dt->format('M')] = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $dt->format('m'), $dt->format('Y')) - $dt->format('d');
        } else {
            $month[$dt->format('M')] = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $dt->format('m'), $dt->format('Y'));
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $month[$end->format('M')] = $end->format('d');
    print_r($month);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks dear, But it is giving only April month days but i need the days of all months in date range.  

array:1 [▼
  "Apr" => "20"
]

Comment: This is output I am getting:
Array
(
    [Dec] => 21
    [Jan] => 31
    [Feb] => 28
    [Mar] => 31
    [Apr] => 20
)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
        //Calculating Number of Days Per Month in given daterange.
$begin = new \Carbon\Carbon($start_date);
$end = new \Carbon\Carbon($end_date);
$month = array();
if ($begin->month != $end->month) {
    $interval = \Carbon\CarbonInterval::month();
    $period = new \DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
    $i = 0;
    $month = array();
    foreach ($period as $dt) {
        if ($i == 0) {
            $month[$dt->month] = $dt->daysInMonth + 1 - $dt->day;
        } else {
            $month[$dt->month] = $dt->daysInMonth;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $month[$end->month] = $end->day;
} else if ($begin->month == $end->month && $begin->diffInDays($end) == 0) {
    $month[$begin->month] = 1;
} else if ($begin->month == $end->month && $begin->diffInDays($end) != 0) {
    $month[$begin->month] = $begin->diffInDays($end) + 1;
}
?>
```